# "At the beginning" or "during the beginning"?

Tags: word-choice, time

Are both expressions below valid and equivalent?

- "At the beginning …"
- "During the beginning …"

"During the beginning …" seems wrong to me.

Comment: There's also "In the beginning" which is a little more extended than "At the beginning" so is similar to "During the beginning" but is much more common.

Answer (score 3):

Valid, yes, equivalent, no.

[at](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/at)

> used to show an exact position or particular place:

[during](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/during)

> from the beginning to the end of a particular period:

Which can be a period known as the "beginning."

Hence, one could say that at the beginning of a class, half the students had arrived, but during the beginning, as the teacher took attendance, all but two arrived.